# Securely deleting/wiping MySQL data from hard disk

Tags: mysql, security, sanitization, erase

We're running MySQL 5.1 on CentOS 5 and I need to securely wipe data. Simply issuing a DELETE query isn't an option, we need to comply with DoD file deletion standards. This will be done on a live production server without taking MySQL down. Short of taking the server down and using a secure deletion utility on the DB files is there a way to do this?

**Update**

The data sanitization will be done once per database when we remove some of the tables. We don't need to delete data continuously. CPU time isn't an issue, these servers are nowhere near capacity.

Answer (score 2):

If you need a really secure open source database, you could take a look at [Security Enhanced PostgreSQL](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/SEPostgreSQL_SELinux_Overview) running on SELinux. A very aggresive vacuum strategy can assure your data gets overwritten quickly. Strong encryption can be of help as well, [pgcrypto](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/pgcrypto.html) has some fine PGP functions.

Comment: Thanks but switching DBs/technology isn't an option.

Answer (score 1):

Not as far as I know, secure deletion requires the CPU to do a bit of work, especially DoD standard which I believe is 3 passes of inflating 1's and 0's. You can, however, encrypt the harddrive. Given that a user would need phsyical access and a password for the CentOS to recover the data. As long as you routinely monitory access logs for suspicious activity on the server, this should be "secure".

While searching found this article: [Six Steps to Secure Sensitive Data in MySQL](http://www.builderau.com.au/program/mysql/soa/Six-steps-to-secure-sensitive-data-in-MySQL/0,339028784,339266102,00.htm)

Short of that though, I do not think a DoD standard wipe is viable or even possible without taking the server down.

**EDIT**

<del>One thing I found is this software: [data wiper](http://www.datadoctor.biz/data-wiper.html).</del> If there is a linux comparable version of that, that might work "wipes unused disk space". But again this may take a major performance toll on your server, so may be advisable to run at night at a set time and I do not know what the re-precautions (if any) of doing this too often to a harddrive.

One other resource is [this forum thread](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-security-4/secure-unused-disk-space-wipes-dd-and-shred-627070/). It talks about wiping unused space etc. From that thread one resource stands out in particular: [secure_deletion toolkit - sfill](http://www.digipedia.pl/man/doc/view/sfill.1). The man page should be helpful.

Comment: sfill in particular and more generally the paper referenced by sfill (Secure Deletion of Data from Magnetic and Solid-State Memory) appear hopelessly irrelevant today.

Answer (score 1):

If it's on a disk, you could just use:  http://lambda-diode.com/software/wipe/